# filling empty spots responsive thumbnail grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using instagrams API and grabbing pictures and some of the contents and putting them into thumbnails. The only sore look of this result is that some of the thumbnails get pushed out because the content may be too big

here is a example

[image]

how about do make some of the resulting thumbnails come up? The end result looking staggered is fine with me(artsy effect). this is my code. Im using handlebars as i'm using the MEAN stack

```
<body align="center">
<h1>
    <p>Hello {{user.username}}!</p>
</h1>
<h2>
    <p>Photos from your feed:</p>
</h2>
 <div class="jumbotron">

 <div class="row">
  {{#each photos}}
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="text-align:center">
 <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="{{url}}" class="img-responsive" class="img hashtag-img"><br>
        <div class="caption" style="text-align:left">
         <p>    {{caption.text}} </p><br>
        <p>Likes: {{likes.count}}
        <form id="like" role="form" method="post" action="/like">
              <input type="hidden" name="link" value="{{link}}">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
        </form>
        <a href="/unlike" class="btn btn-warning" role="button" align="center">Unlike</a>
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    {{/each}}
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Jquery Grid-A-Licious` plugin to do this. Because Grid-A-Licious does automatic placing of objects based on the width and height. Here is the link for Grid-A-Licious     http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/ check this out.

For example

```
    $("#example1").gridalicious({
        width: 50
    });
```

where width is your thumbnails width.